# Storing output from setfill and setw to a string

Tags: c++, string

I am trying to produce binary numbers using C's `itoa` function and C++ `setfill` and `setw` function. If I use only `itoa`, the output displayed does not have proper `0` padding.

This is a small code snippet.

```
int s = 8;
for (int i = 1; i<s;i++)
    {
        itoa(i,buffer,2);
        cout<<setfill('0')<<setw(3)<<endl;
        cout<<buffer<<endl;
    }
```

Now it does a great job in printing out the output.

If I hadn't used setfill and setw, the formatting would have been something like

```
1
10
11
100
101
110
111
```

instead of

```
001
010
011
100
101
110
111
```

Now I want to store the padded binary numbers produced and store it into a vector. Is it possible?

I think I have got a solution using bitset, and it works fine.

```
    std::ostringstream oss;
    int s = 3;
    for (int i = 1; i<s;i++)
    {
        itoa(i,buffer,2);
        oss<<setfill('0')<<setw(3);
        oss<<buffer;

        string s = oss.str();
        cout<<s<<'\n'<<endl;

    };
```

However, I just want to point out that the solution I obtained looks some this![image: Bin]

Can it manipulated by flushing out streams in consecutive iterations. Its just an afterthought.

Comment: Are you looking for [`std::ostringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream)?

Comment: AFAIK, there is no `itoa()` in `c99` standard. maybe you're using a compiler extension that supports this function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider using a `bitset` instead of `itoa`:

```
#include <bitset>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main() {
  std::vector<std::string> binary_representations;

  int s = 8;
  for (int i = 1; i < s; i++)
  {
    binary_representations.push_back(std::bitset<3>(i).to_string());
  }
}
```

EDIT: If you need a variable length, one possibility is

```
// Note: it might be better to make x unsigned here.
// What do you expect to happen if x < 0?
std::string binary_string(int x, std::size_t len) {
  std::string result(len, '0');

  for(std::string::reverse_iterator i = result.rbegin(); i != result.rend(); ++i) {
    *i = x % 2 + '0';
    x /= 2;
  }

  return result;
}
```

and then later

```
binary_representations.push_back(binary_string(i, 3));
```

Comment: Yes, thanks for the reply, it works, but do you want to anything about why shouldn't I use itoa.

Comment: Mainly because it's easier (it already does exactly what you want). In general, though, it's best to avoid working with C-style strings in C++ unless you have a really good reason to use them because it's so easy to go wrong with them -- your buffer could be too short, you could forget zero-terminators (thanks, `snprintf`!), you can forget to `free` what you `strdup`, that sort of thing. If you're using equivalent C++ constructs, those kinds of errors are harder to make. Oh, and `itoa` in particular isn't very portable (I don't have it on Linux).

Comment: Sorry, just realizing it later, what does 3 in bitset<3> represents- is it the fact that 2^3 = 8? And also can 3 be replaced by a variable? Thanks.

Comment: It means that the bitset has three bits. So...yes, actually, but the reason I suggested using it is that the string representation of a `bitset<N>` is `N` characters long regardless of the number it represents. Which I suppose is the same thing said in a different way.

Comment: I want to use it like this int x = 4; bitset<x>(1).to_string(). Is it possible.Visual Studio is saying that bitset< > only accepts constants, not variables.

Comment: No, that's not possible; `bitset` is a class template, so its parameters have to be known at compile time. It's not difficult to do it with a variable, though. Hold on a moment, I'll edit something in.

Comment: Haha, old school, binary computation. I was thinking of something fancier. Anyhow I am trying on it.

Comment: There are some mistakes in notation; eg string result(len); its not a valid syntax and it is creating a problem. Do you want to change it?

Comment: Oh, good catch; `string` doesn't have just a length constructor. But it works if you tell it what character to fill it with (any will do, since it'll be overwritten in the loop). Edited that in.